# Fail compiling boost-1.82.0 using clang-16.0.0 in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, clang++, msys2

I used pacman to install clang-16 on windows 10, then set the path on environment. My target is to build boost 1.82.0 and use both clang and boost to compile a project.

Installing clang-16 works fine,

```
> clang++.exe --version
clang version 16.0.5
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Followed steps to compile boost as

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=../boost-x86-64/1.82.0 --with-python-version=3.8
./b2 toolset=clang variant=release install
```

which didn't comipled successfully with error as

```
fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found
#    include <cstddef>
             ^~~~~~~~~
```

however, the library include and lib is available under `1.82.0` directory and I've tried to comiple the `first.cpp` example from boost

```
>clang++.exe -I"C:\Users\example\boost-x86_64\1.82.0\include" -L"C:\Users\example\boost-x86_64\1.82.0\lib" -o first first.cpp -lboost_program_option
```

gives me error of Permission denied.

```
C:/Users/example/clang/16.0.0/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_option: Permission denied
```

I've got that while linking with `boost_program_option`, the error is generated, but how / what does this Permission denied means?

Comment: `pacman` means you're using MSYS2, right? You know you can download prebuilt Boost from it? If it's indeed MSYS2, how did its Clang end up outside of its installation directory, in `C:/Users/example/clang/16.0.0`?

Comment: I've copied the installed files (clang), and set the path in environment. It works.

Comment: Well it obviously doesn't work, it's lost access to its standard library

Comment: 1. Why did you copy it? 2. What about the rest of my comment?

Comment: 1. I copied it to get an independent copy deployment of clang, so it possible to use it without always compiling.
2. No I didn't tried pacman for boost, I'll give a try now.
I'd put the tag msys2.

Comment: The clang works, I've tested example program with cstddef, and it runs without segfault. But somehow boost won't compile, I believe somewhere b2 is unable to link the stdlib.

But my main concern is, why/how permission denied appear?